# Use Bat file to split a string with semi-colon as delimiter

Tags: batch-file, path

I want to delete a special path using batch.

I cannot use `set somevar=" %path:specialstr=%"`,because the `specialstr` has dynamic part. Can I use batch to remove strings which are produced by `%cd%` from a large string like `%path%`？

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of the paths you are working with? and the desired output?

Comment: Have you tried using `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and then `set somevar="!path:%specialstr%!"`? That way you can use a variable specialstr in the replace.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [2-minute tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Moreover,  [edit] your question and add a [mcve], please.

Comment: sorry for my poor format and unreadable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow  [Dennis van Gils' advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017804/use-bat-file-to-split-a-string-with-semi-colon-as-delimiter#comment63478503_38017804), use [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as follows:

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "specialstr=%CD%\"
set "somevar=!path:;%specialstr%;=;!"
```

If you can't use Delayed Expansion for some reason, use `call set` (read [Advanced usage : CALLing internal commands](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)):

- *warning*: some partial paths in `%path%` variable contain *facultative* trailing backslash whereas other do not.
- `call set "somevar=%%path:;%specialstr%;=;%%"` most common usage.
- `call set "somevar=%%path:;%specialstr%=%%"` use if `;%specialstr%` is trailing part of `%path%`  but **be aware** that [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) is *greedy* and replaces **all occurences** of `;%specialstr%` in `%path%`.
- `call set "somevar=%%path:%specialstr%;=%%"` use if `%specialstr%;` is leading part of `%path%` but **be careful** for *the same caution*.

A sample script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
where p.bat
pushd "C:\Utils"
set "specialstr=%CD%\"
popd
echo  specialstr=%specialstr%
echo    path end=...%path:~-46%
call set "somevar=%%path:;%specialstr%=%%"       
echo somevar end=...%somevar:~-36%
SETLOCAL
    set "path=%somevar%" 
    echo    path end=...%path:~-36%
    where p.bat
ENDLOCAL
where p.bat
```

**Output** (shows only some few trailing characters of `%path%` and `%somevar%` variables for better readability):

```
==> D:\bat\SO\38017804.bat
C:\Utils\p.bat
 specialstr=C:\Utils\
   path end=...Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Utils\
somevar end=...Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\
   path end=...Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
C:\Utils\p.bat
```

Comment: I suggest to change `set "specialstr=%CD%\"` to `if "%CD:~-1%" == "\" ( set "specialstr=%CD%" ) else ( set "specialstr=%CD%\" )` because the directory path of environment variable __CD__ is without backslash __except__ the current directory is the root directory of a drive as in this case the path of __CD__ ends already with a backslash.

Comment: @Mofi you are right. I agree that my code **is not _bullet-proof_**. It's merely a sample  and _bullet-proofness_ is not my aim in this particular case. Please take note of all _warning_, _be aware_, _be careful_… The OQ is a bit unclear…